# Problem with Jquery in Durpal 7

Tags: javascript, theming, .info

I am using Drupal 7 and bootstrap theme, I also have installed jquery update module,

Now I have created a js (jquery) file and saved it under js folder in bootstrap theme, I tried to call my js file in the info file using script[] = '...', the console then suggested  that '$ is not a function', which means my js file was called before jquery was called.

Then I decided to call the my js file from template.php:

```
function bootstrap_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
  $options = array(
    'group' => JS_THEME,
  );
  drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'bootstrap'). 'js/product_pages.js', $options);
}
```

then the following line showed up in the console:

```
GET http://localhost/Brompton/sites/all/themes/bootstrapjs/product_pages.js?mpprnf 404 (Not Found)
```

I am confused, how exactly can I get jquery work properly here?

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please read [this introductory text](http://drupal.org/node/756722), especially **Using jQuery** and **Behaviors** parts of it. *"which means my js file was called before jquery was called."* is false, it only means your file uses jQuery without proper namespacing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically you've got two Problems. The first one is namespacing, like Molot pointet out. To use $ for jQuery you need at least to wrap your code into this construct:

```
(function ($) {
  $('body').fancystuff();
})(jQuery);
```

That's enough for getting your code executed, for the drupal way you need to attach a behaviour to the Drupal object like the tutorial in [Molot's link](https://drupal.org/node/756722) shows.

The second problem is a missing slash in your drupal_add_js:

```
drupal_get_path('theme', 'bootstrap') . '/' .'js/product_pages.js'
```